# How to get exception message in Axios from a Spring boot backend

Tags: java, reactjs, spring-boot, exception, axios

I use a spring boot back with react front. Api calls are with axios. Now in Spring Controller I handle exceptions and throw another one for React to extract a message from (I really need this message). But all i get is "Request failed with status code 500". How can I get this message?
My controller:

```
@DeleteMapping("/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<?> delete(@PathVariable("id") Integer id) throws RuntimeException {
        log.info("Request for delete settings {}", id);
        try{
            Settings settings = settingsService.findById(id);
        settingsService.delete(settings.getId());
        log.info("SUCCESS: {} deleted.", settings.getId());
        return new ResponseEntity<>(settings.getId() + " deleted successfully.", HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            System.out.println("CAUSE Controller: "+e.getCause().getMessage());
            throw new RuntimeException("Error during deletion: " + e.getCause().getMessage());
        }
    }
```

SettingsApiService.js:

```
delete(id) {
        return axios.delete(`${BASE_URL}/${id}`, ApiService.getAuthHeader());
    }
```

Now I have a "Table" component which i reuse a lot. And send the deletion method as a prop from every respecting component.
This one is from the Settings component

```
 <Table
                    ref='table'
                    getTr={this.getTr()}
                    getUrl={this.getUrl(idType)}
                    columns={this.getColumns()}
                    updateSelectedItem={this.updateSelectedItem}
                    deleteItem={this.deleteItem}
                    isSettings={true}
                    showDelete={showDelete}
                    toggleShowDelete={this.toggleShowDelete}
                />
```

And the Deleteitem method in Settings I send is:

```
deleteItem = async () => {
        await SettingsApiService.delete(this.state.selectedId);
    };
```

And in Table component I delete with a button like this:

```
<Button
                            variant='primary'
                            onClick={() => {
                                globalProps
                                    .deleteItem()
                                    .then((res) => {
                                        console.log(res);
                                        table.draw();
                                    })
                                    .catch((e) => {
                                        console.log(e);
                                        this.setState({ error: e.message });
                                        this.setState({ showModalBatch: true });
                                    });
                                this.props.toggleShowDelete();
                            }}
                        >
                            Delete
                        </Button>
```

I want the e.message to be the one I threw in Controller. How do I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- On Axios you can access the body of the error response in "error.response.data".
- On your spring boot I recommend to use [@ControllerAdvice](https://www.baeldung.com/exception-handling-for-rest-with-spring) to customize your response according to your needs.

An example:

```
@ExceptionHandler(MyCustomException.class)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
@ResponseBody
public MyCustomResponse myCustomException(MyCustomException e) {
 return new MyCustomResponse(e.getStatusCode(), e.getStatusMessage());
}
```

- So following the example, in your code you will throw a MyCustomException, then you will intercept it in your @ControllerAdvice component and you will return in a JSON format a MyCustomResponse.

Your custom response body will look something like this:

```
{ statusCode: 1002, statusMessage: "My custom error message" }
```

So now that you are returning this body on the response you can access it on your axios on "error.response.data.statusMessage".

Please check that on the example the http status code (@ResponseStatus) is set to 500, but you can customize it to your requirement.